# Pysub the entire document

Tags: best-practices, pythontex

In `pythontex` the `pysub` environment provides a nice syntax to refer to python variables (for example `!{a}`) inside your latex code.

Suppose you have only one pythontex session in your document. Is there any reason why I should not use `pysub` just for the whole document? I.e. something like

```
%Preamble
\begin{document}
\begin{pysub}
%% a complex document
\end{pysub}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some things may not work, like `\begin{pysub} \pyc{var = 4} The value of var is !{var}. \end{pysub}`.